How to use regex in LOAD FROM instruction, in qliksense?
Usually, I load qvd using this :
Table_Name:
LOAD
    *
FROM [lib://Datalake/file_path/qvd_name_202*.qvd]
(qvd)

Is there a way to find to load only the years from 2024 to 2029, like :
Table_Name:
LOAD
    *
FROM [lib://Datalake/file_path/qvd_name_202[4-9]*.qvd]
(qvd)

Of course, I could use a loop but I'm looking for a solution that's not too verbose and easy to understand for other devs.

As far as im aware this is not possible. It has been requested for some time now. Unfortunately loop is the way to go
